# No matching two dimensional string arrays for a login

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, authentication, multidimensional-array

I was resolving an example I see in a book about C programming. This particular problem I saw in this book was about matching a kind of 'customer code'(integer) which was okay for me. But I have troubles applying the same logic for a two dimensional string where I want to prove my login.

This is from the book, which goes fine.

```
/*
This program searches a sorted list of customer IDs in order to get credit totals
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ctr; // Loop counter
    int idSearch; // Customer to look for (the key)
    int found = 0; // 1 (true) if customer is found

    /* Defines the 10 elements in each of the parallel arrays */
    int custID[10] = {313, 453, 502, 101, 892, 475, 792, 912, 343, 633};
    float custBal[10]={0.00, 45.43, 71.23, 301.56, 9.08, 192.41, 389.00, 229.67, 18.31, 59.54};
    int tempID, inner, outer, didSwap, i; // For sorting
    float tempBal;

    // First, sort the arrays by customer ID
    for (outer=0; outer<9; outer++)
    {
        didSwap=0; // Becomes 1 (true) if list is not yet ordered
        for (inner=outer; inner<10; inner++)
        {
            if (custID[inner] < custID[outer])
            {
                tempID = custID[inner];     // Must switch both arrays of they
                tempBal = custBal[inner];   // are no longer linked

                custID[inner] = custID[outer];
                custBal[inner] = custBal[outer];
                custID[outer] = tempID;
                custBal[outer]=tempBal;
                didSwap = 1;    // True because a swap took place
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Interact with the user looking to find a balance */
    printf("\n\n*** Customer Balance Lookup ***\n");
    printf("What is the customer number? ");
    scanf(" %d", &idSearch);

    // Now, look for the ID in the array
    for (ctr=0; ctr<10; ctr++)
    {
        if (idSearch == custID[ctr]) // Do they match?
        {
            found = 1;  // Yes, match flag is set to TRUE
            break;      // No need to keep looping
        }
        if (custID[ctr] >idSearch) // No need to keep searching
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Once the loop has completed, the ID was either found
    // (found = 1) of not

    if (found)
    {
        if (custBal[ctr]>100)
        {
            printf("\n** That customer's balance is $%.2f.\n", custBal[ctr]);
            printf("No additional credit.\n");
        }
        else    // Balance is less than $100.00
        {
            printf("\n**The customer's credit is good!\n");
        }
    }
    else    // The ID was not found
    {
        printf("** You have entered an incorrect customer ID.");
        printf("\n ID %3d was not found in the list.\n", idSearch);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

This is what I tried to create in order to do a login.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int ctr; // Loop counter
    char userSearch[20], passSearch[10]; // to look for (the key)
    int found = 0; // 1 (true) if it is found

    /* Defines the 5 elements in each of the parallel arrays */
    char user[5][20] = {"John", "Ivan", "Paul", "Robert", "Leo"};
    char pass[5][10]={"1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555"};
    int inner, outer, didSwap, i; // For sorting
    char tempUser, tempPass;

    for (outer=0; outer<4; outer++)
    {
        didSwap=0; // Becomes 1 (true) if list is not yet ordered
        for (inner=outer; inner<5; inner++) 
        {
            if (user[inner] != user[outer])
            {
                strcpy(tempUser, user[inner]);    
                strcpy(tempPass, pass[inner]); 

                strcpy(user[inner], user[outer]);
                strcpy(pass[inner], pass[outer]);
                strcpy(user[outer], tempUser);
                strcpy(pass[outer], tempPass);
                didSwap = 1; 
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("User: ");
    scanf(" %s", userSearch);
    printf("Password: ");
    scanf(" %s", passSearch);


    for (ctr=0; ctr<5; ctr++)
    {
        if ((strcmp(userSearch, user[ctr])==0) && (strcmp(passSearch, pass[ctr])==0)) // Do they match?
        {
            found = 1; 
            break;      
        }

    }

    if (found)
    {
        printf("You entered sucessfully.");
    }
    else    
    {
        printf("** You have entered an incorrect data.");
        printf("\n %s was not found.\n", userSearch);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

What exactly is wrong with my last code? How can I get to make a proper login with two-dimensional string arrays? I want to put like 100 users for example, and pointing each user is not an option so I thought this way would be a good idea, with this algorithm. But not sure what is my mistake.

Comment: `char tempUser, tempPass;` -> `char tempUser[20], tempPass[10];`

Comment: `user[inner] != user[outer]` That condition is not correct. The original code uses `<` so why do you use `!=`? You'll need to use `strcmp` and check for `< 0`.

Comment: Because in the first program that was for quantities and what I wrote is for strings. I supposed saying just "less than" would be uncorrect talking about 'words'. But it is right, I prove the code just like that. Can you explain why it is correct?

Comment: @Joel indeed, you can't use `s1 < s2` directly to compare strings, but kaylum is telling you that you can use `strcmp(s1, s2) < 0` instead. Just comparing the strings with `!=` is wrong for two reasons: (1) it breaks the logic of the algorithm, which required a "less than" comparison, not a "not equal" comparison; (2) comparing two strings with `!=` in language C doesn't actually compare the strings the way a human would, looking at the characters that compose them; instead, it compares the addresses at which they are stored in memory.

Comment: Joel, Tip: Increase productivity. `char tempUser, tempPass; ... strcpy(tempUser, user[inner]);` --> Enable all compiler warnings and save time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Stef . So you're saying this algorithm needs the "less than" comparison, but I'm not sure if I understand why. Would you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @chux thanks for the advice. I think I'll press more attention to the compiler from now on.